# Better error message for UCWA API for Skype for Business

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa

I am trying to get contact information from a Skype for Business 2019 server using the UCWA API. I've managed to get an access token, but when I try to search for a contact I get a 500 error with the message `There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.` If I understand correctly this is a general error message and it should be possible to get a better error message. I have access to the server and can change all settings, but don't know where or how. I am a (PHP) programmer with no experience configuring Skype for Business or IIS. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: have you found any solution to the problem? I have the same issue. @RudyGnodde